# Proving connectedness of punctured disc without using path-connectedness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Using path-connectedness it is easy to see that the punctured disc $$D:=\lbrace(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:0<x^2+y^2<1\rbrace$$ is connected. I was wondering if there is a proof that $D$ is a connected set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ from the definition of connectedness, or without using path-connectedness ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intervals $(0,1),[0,2\pi]$ are connected. Hence $(0,1)\times[0,2\pi)$ is connected. Consider the function $f:(0,1)\times[0,2\pi)\rightarrow D$ that sends $(r,\theta)$ to $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$. It is easy to verify that $f$ is continuous and surjective. Thus $D$ is the continuous image of $f$. Hence $D$ is connected.

Comment: You probably want $(0,1)\times[0,2\pi]$ instead.

Comment: Yes. you are right. Tthanks

Comment: Woudn't it be $f:(0,1)\times [0,2\pi)\to D$ ?

Comment: There is no need to ensure that $f$ is injective

Comment: @pritam, yes I thought I wrote $[0,2\pi]$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Prove that it is the continuous image of a connected space.

Answer (score 3):

- Identify the plane $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $ with $ \mathbb{C} $.
- The punctured plane is the image of the plane under the exponential function.
- As $ \mathbb{C} $ is connected and $ \exp $ is continuous, the punctured plane is thus connected.
- The punctured disk is homeomorphic to the punctured plane. Therefore, the punctured disk is connected as well.

**Note:** As $ \mathbb{R} $ is connected, we see that the plane $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $, and hence $ \mathbb{C} $, is connected in the first place.

Comment: C=R*R R is connected hence C

Comment: @Haskell Curry, did part of your answer get chopped off?

Comment: Yes. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @Azmoti: Having chopped-off answers is the consequence of writing math with the touchscreen keypad of an iPad. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here I found another soloution based on complex exponentiation: Let's consider the set $S:=(-\infty ,0]\times[0,2\pi)$ which is connected and $f:S\to D$ is defined as $$f(x,y)=(e^x\cos y,e^x\sin y)$$ Then $f$ is continous and $f(S)=D$.